# Ruby On Rails: pass params to link_to to call the create path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am writing a report module that allows users to select the dates of the report and export the corresponding report to excel. So, I use a active model to store the dates. In the view, I have a link for users to download reports. I want it goes to the create action in the controller so that I can get the report with correct date.

```
<%= render partial: 'reports/select_dates_form' %>
        <p>
            Download:
            <%= link_to "Excel", reports_A_reports_path(:report, :end_date => @report.end_date, :start_date => @report.start_date), :method => :post, format: "xls" %>
        </p>
```

In the controller, I defined a `create_param` method to define the params.

```
def create_params
    params.require(:reports_A_report).permit(:end_date, :start_date)
end
```

However, it gives error "param is missing or the value is empty: reports_A_report". I try to various way to pass the params but still cannot success.

Comment: `link_to` and `post method` no noooo...

Comment: are you using something like jquery_ujs?

Answer (score 4):

In the standard REST scheme the index action and the create action both have the same url
(/reports) and only differ in that index is accessed using GET and create is accessed using POST. So `link_to :action => :create` will simply generate a link to `/reports` which will cause the browser to perform a GET request for `/reports` when clicked and thus invoke the index action.

To invoke the create action use `link_to {:action => :create}, :method => :post`, telling `link_to` explicitly that you want a post request, or use a form with a submit button rather than a link.

Try

```
<%= link_to "Text_to_dispaly", :controller => "controller_name", :action => "action_name, :method => :post" %>
```

Also, `method` is for choosing the HTTP method (GET, POST, ...). It's not method as in routine.

Be sure to check out **[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)** and The **[Lowdown on Routes in Rails 3](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/)**, they're both awesome resources.

I hope my answer help you..